401 Unauthorized Error when fetching Apple's public keys
I keep getting 401 Unauthorized error when fetching Apple's public keys.
In [14]: print(f"Error fetching public keys: {response.status_code} {response.text}")
Error fetching public keys: 401 Unauthenticated
I've verified that the Key ID, Issuer ID, and private key file are all correct, with the private key having admin access. The server time is correctly set to UTC. Given this, I can't identify what might be causing the issue. Any insights?
def generate_apple_developer_token():
    # Load the private key in PEM format
    with open(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, 'rb') as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=None,
            backend=default_backend()
        )

    # JWT header
    headers = {
        "alg": "ES256",  # Algorithm: Elliptic Curve
        "kid": KEY_ID,   # Key ID from Apple Developer
        "typ": "JWT"     # Type: JWT
    }

    # JWT payload
    payload = {
        "iss": ISSUER_ID,  # Issuer ID from Apple Developer
        "iat": int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()),  # Issued at time
        "exp": int((datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=10)).timestamp()),  # Expiration (max 10 minutes)
        "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",  # Audience
        
    }

    # Encode the header and payload as base64
    header_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(json.dumps(headers).encode()).decode().rstrip("=")
    payload_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(json.dumps(payload).encode()).decode().rstrip("=")

    # Concatenate header and payload
    message = f"{header_base64}.{payload_base64}".encode()

    # Sign the message using ECDSA with SHA256
    signature = private_key.sign(
        message,
        ec.ECDSA(hashes.SHA256())
    )

    # Convert the DER-encoded signature to raw format (r and s concatenated)
    der_to_raw_ecdsa_format = lambda der: der[4:36] + der[-32:]

    # Convert the signature to raw format (64 bytes)
    signature_64 = der_to_raw_ecdsa_format(signature)

    # Base64 URL-encode the signature
    signature_base64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature_64).decode().rstrip("=")

    # Concatenate header, payload, and signature to form the JWT
    jwt_token = f"{header_base64}.{payload_base64}.{signature_base64}"

    return jwt_token

def get_apple_public_keys():
    try:
        # Generate a fresh JWT
        developer_token = generate_apple_developer_token()

        # Set up headers with the authorization token
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {developer_token}"
        }

        # Fetch the public keys from Apple
        response = requests.get('https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/in-app-purchase/publicKeys', headers=headers)
         # Log the response if it's not successful
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error fetching public keys: {response.status_code} {response.text}")
        
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an exception for 4xx/5xx errors

        # Parse and return the public keys
        response_data = response.json()
        keys = response_data.get('keys')
        if not keys:
            print("No 'keys' found in the response from Apple.")
            return []
        return keys
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching Apple's public keys: {e}")
        return []

I also tried using jwt to implement the jwt token
def generate_apple_developer_token():
    with open(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, 'r') as f:
        private_key = f.read().strip()
        print('this is the key', private_key)
    # JWT header
    headers = {
        "alg": "ES256",  # Apple uses ES256 (Elliptic Curve)
        "kid": KEY_ID,
        "typ": "JWT"
    }

    # JWT payload
    payload = {
        "iss": ISSUER_ID,
        "iat": int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()),  # Issued at time
        "exp": int((datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=10)).timestamp()),  # Expiration (max 10 minutes)
        "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
    
    }

    # Generate and return the JWT
    return jwt.encode(payload, private_key, algorithm="ES256", headers=headers)

In either case, I checked the token in jwt.io and they are correct, but for some reason they fail the authentication

Are you confident that your JWT implementation is correct?  Have you validated its output using something like https://jwt.io ? Have you tried with a JWT package rather than using your own implementation?

@Paulw11  yes, I have validated the JWT token with jwt.io, the header, payload, verify signature are all correct

Apple support gives me the answer here and it works
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/766360
Use this library instead https://github.com/apple/app-store-server-library-python
